# No Material widget found

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I was trying do execute the example [here](https://flutter.io/text-input/). I just want to use the TextField widget to get some user input. The issue is that I get a "No Material widget found." error. What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new ExampleWidget(),
    );
  }
}


/// Opens an [AlertDialog] showing what the user typed.
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ExampleWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleWidgetState createState() => new _ExampleWidgetState();
}

/// State for [ExampleWidget] widgets.
class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Type something',
          ),
        ),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              child: new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('What you typed'),
                content: new Text(_controller.text),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: new Text('DONE'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error stack:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk (21.5MB).
I/flutter ( 5187): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5187): The following assertion was thrown building InputDecorator(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText:
I/flutter ( 5187): "Type something"); baseStyle: null; isFocused: false; isEmpty: true; dirty):
I/flutter ( 5187): No Material widget found.
I/flutter ( 5187): InputDecorator widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
I/flutter ( 5187): In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
I/flutter ( 5187): material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
I/flutter ( 5187): that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
I/flutter ( 5187): there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
I/flutter ( 5187): To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
I/flutter ( 5187): Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
I/flutter ( 5187): The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
I/flutter ( 5187):   InputDecorator(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Type something"); baseStyle: null;
I/flutter ( 5187):   isFocused: false; isEmpty: true)
I/flutter ( 5187): The ownership chain for the affected widget is:
I/flutter ( 5187):   InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ←
I/flutter ( 5187):   GestureDetector ← TextField ← Column ← ExampleWidget ← _ModalScopeStatus ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 5187): 
I/flutter ( 5187): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5187): #0      debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:26)
I/flutter ( 5187): #2      debugCheckHasMaterial (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:23)
I/flutter ( 5187): #3      InputDecorator.build (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:334)
... <output omitted>
I/flutter ( 5187): (elided one frame from class _AssertionError)
I/flutter ( 5187): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5187): Another exception was thrown: No Material widget found.
```

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The error message says:

> To introduce a `Material` widget, you can either directly include one,
>   or use a widget that contains `Material` itself, such as a `Card`,
>   `Dialog`, `Drawer`, or `Scaffold`.

In your case, I'd probably wrap your `Column` in a `Scaffold`. This will make it easy to add other material widgets to your app later, such as an `AppBar`, `Drawer`, or `FloatingActionButton`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Type something',
            ),
        ),
        new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  child: new AlertDialog(
                      title: new Text('What you typed'),
                      content: new Text(_controller.text),
                  ),
              );
            },
            child: new Text('DONE'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The challange with this approach is that the new page does not contain either the bottom navigationbar or the theme of the app, can we have two MaterialApps in the same app?

Answer (score 34):

Just Wrap your Widegt with **`Material widget`**, it fixes the problem.

```
Material(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: onPressed,));
```

Comment: this is a much better fix

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I was using a hero widget Inside a scaffold-like this

```
Scaffold(
  body:Hero(
    child:ListView(
      children:<Widget>[
        TextField(),
           ...
           ...
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

I simply moved the Hero Widget Outside Scaffold and it solved the problem

```
Hero(
  child:Scaffold(
    body:ListView(
      children:<Widget>[
        TextField(),
        ...
        ...
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Put your widget inside a Scaffold, like this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Demo',
          //home: MyWidget(), --> do not do this !!!
          home: Home() --> this will wrap it in Scaffold
        );
      }
    }

    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Demo'),
            ),
            body: MyWidget()); --> put your widget here
      }
    }

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `InkWell` use `GestureDetector` widget, for me fixed issue.

Comment: same here! this fixed the issue, thanks <3

Answer (score 3):

The error means you have to wrap the column inside a Material widget, you could place it as a body to the scaffold or place it as a home to Materialapp. for instance:

```
 return MaterialApp(
   home: Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
       TextField(
         controller: _controller,
         decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Type something'),
       ),
     ]
   ),
 );
```

or

```
return MaterialApp(
   body: Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
       TextField(
         controller: _controller,
         decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Type something'),
       ),
     ]
   ),
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your Column with Scaffold or Material

Answer (score 2):

I used below approach while using hero animation widget.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isKeyboardShowing = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.vertical > 0;
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Hero(
          tag: AppStrings.imageSignIn,
          child: Material(
            child: Container()),
```

Personal Recommendation : Not use Hero widget above the scaffold because it stays in widget tree and it will throw exception while showing any snackbar on the screen.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by wrong routes.

Check your routes one by one.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this method: simply add the line `builder` to `MaterialApp`:

```dart
builder: (context, child) => Material(child: child),
```

Here you can also provide a typical page with `AppBar`, `Body`, `ScrollConfiguration`, `Platform` and other elements as you wish (you can even add global listeners). It's just very convenient :) And any page along the route will be wrapped.

> For example, from the BuildContext passed to this method, the Directionality, Localizations, DefaultTextStyle, MediaQuery, etc, are all available. They can also be overridden in a way that impacts all the routes in the Navigator or Router.

> This is rarely useful, but can be used in applications that wish to override those defaults, e.g. to force the application into right-to-left mode despite being in English, or to override the MediaQuery metrics (e.g. to leave a gap for advertisements shown by a plugin from OEM code).

Answer (score -8):

The easy fix is:

Instead of using:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

You should use:

```
void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp()
  )
);
```

Hope this helps you!