# Does flutter_test support testing 'leaf' widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Suppose I create a simple widget, such as this:

```
class RightArrowButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RightArrowButton({VoidCallback onPressed})
      : this._onPressed = onPressed;

  final VoidCallback _onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      onPressed: _onPressed,
      icon: _buildIcon(iconData()),
    );
  }

  /// Overrride to set a different icon.
  IconData iconData() => Icons.play_arrow;

  Widget _buildIcon(IconData icon) => Icon(icon, color: Colors.blue);
}
```

Further suppose that I wish to unit test this widget. I know, this is an incredibly simple widget, but I might be attempting to use TDD to write the widget in the first place. In any case, I could apply the concept to a more complex widget.

In this case, the test would be very simple: Construct the widget, passing it an onPressed function whose side-effects can be checked to validate that the onPressed method is actually called when someone taps on the widget.

Sample test code:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('RightArrowButton', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    int counter = 0;

    await tester.pumpWidget(RightArrowButton(
      onPressed: () => counter++,
    ));
    
    expect(0, equals(counter));

    var button = find.byType(IconButton);
    await tester.tap(button);
    
    expect(1, equals(counter));
  });
}
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building IconButton(Icon, padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), dirty):
No Material widget found.
IconButton widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
```

I understand the error after reading this SO question:

[No Material widget found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947552/no-material-widget-found)

So -- Is there a way to unit test widgets in the way I want? Or am I forced to test a whole assembly of widgets in order to get a valid Material widget ancestor (which is more like a small integration test)?

Comment: The Flutter documentation seems to regard widget tests as different from unit tests and integration tests (see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing), a bit like if widget tests were between the other two types of test.

Comment: Yes, I read that. I prefer a 'bottom-up' approach to testing, where I test the smallest units possible and then 'climb the tree' towards more and more integration. With the approach advocated by the documentation, you have to wait until you have a working app and then test the whole thing, more or less. But see my work-around below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works. Flutter experts, is the following approach the only or best way to achieve my goal of testing individual widgets in isolation?

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('arrow test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    int counter = 0;

    // must include Card to get Material; 
    // must include MaterialApp to get Directionality
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: Card(
        child: RightArrowButton(
          onPressed: () => counter++,
        ),
      ),
    ));

    await tester.tap(find.byType(RightArrowButton));

    expect(1, equals(counter));
  });
}
```